# In presentation mode, Keynote renders vector graphics badly (imported as PDF)

Tags: pdf, graphics, keynote

I want to have my logo as vector graphic in Keynote.

Although Keynote offers nice basic functionality to create vector graphics, it doesn't seem to import SVG or any other vector file format.

I read that at least it allows im import PDF files that have vectors in them. So I tried - and it works great, at least in edit mode:

[image: logo with very smooth edges]

But in presentation mode, it looks really awful:

[image: logo with ugly edges]

Is there something I can do? Or should I simply import the logo as a rasterized image?

Comment: I don't see these effects with vector PDFs. And I can import SVGs perfectly fine, including breaking them apart for converting into shapes. Which macOS and iWork/Keynote version do you use? (IIRC, SVG support was added in iWork 13.1). Which application was used to generate/export the logo vector file?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to creating stunning visual content in Keynote presentations every little detail counts - including the quality and resolution of logos contained within any given PDF file you wish to integrate. This is where one of the online pdf tools I use, [pdfsimpli](https://pdfsimpli.com/pdf-editor/) comes in:

1. Begin by uploading your original PDF logo file onto their platform.
2. Choose from a variety of compatible vector formats (such as SVG) that will ensure no loss of image quality or detail when transferred over into Keynote Format.
3. Once converted download your new vector logo element with ease; then insert it directly into any desired slide or presentation template without fuss.
4. Customize further as required: adjusting size or other design attributes according to slide or style requirements.